# NestJS. Why decorator Global not working?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, inversion-of-control, nest

I have 2 modules. One (payment) is responsible for payments. The second (auth) should send a verification request to a third-party server.
I wanted to make the (auth) module global so that I can freely inject its methods and not use "export" and "import" for my "providers".
But for some reason this doesn't work, the @Global decorator seems to be simply ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Example on codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-forked-gsy160?file=/src/auth/auth.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use `exports` to allow access to the module's public providers. Once you add in `exports` this will work fine.

You can think of a module like a container with its private API (non-exported providers), public API (exported providers), entrypoints (controllers, resolvers, gateways) and configurations (imports). You need to export the providers to make them public and available. The `@Global()` will just mean you don't need to add the `AuthModule` to other module's `imports` (besides your root module)